# Filed earlier, published later

Tags: prior, art

US patent claiming Compound A or its salt (X salt included in laundry list) published after another US application filed as compound A's X salt and gets grant. They do not share common priority and inventors except applicant. Later patent can be challenged or can earlier patent be prior art for later patent?

Comment: Are you saying they do have one common inventor?

Comment: No common inventor but applicant is same

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the filing dates. If application A is filed first then application A may be considered prior art for application B even if application B is filed before application A publishes. It doesn't matter whether or not application B was developed independently of patent A. This is true even if the application A never gets granted as a patent.

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.